# Hyper-V Backup (CheckPoint) still occurring even though it's disabled under Integration Services

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, virtual-machines, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I'm having an issue where my Hyper-V Host runs the Backup (volume copy) integration service on my VM even though I disabled it. Do changes regarding integration services only take into effect after the VM has been restarted? Will an outdated integration services toolset cause this issue as well? I'm at a loss here.

- VM: Server 2012 R2 Standard
- Generation: 2
- Host: Server 2012 R2 Standard
- Hyper-V Version: 6.3.9600.16384

Please let know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 0):

VSS was running on the disk that the VM was sitting on. Disabled the service helped remediate the issue temporarily until the we find the culprit that is triggering the VSS process.